# Covered Call With Stock At Loss

Tags: taxes

I bought shares of Macy's  at $29. The stock is now $16 and  I'm thinking of exiting the position and taking the loss.

I was thinking of writing 25  Nov 15th $16.50 covered calls  at 11 cents. I'd make around $250. If assigned, can I take the profit from the options and still take the capital loss if it is called away at $16.50?

Comment: Are you talking about from a tax perspective? The profit from the option will partially offset the loss form the stock if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you , that is all I was looking for

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag. Where are you?

Comment: Yes, you get to claim both (U.S.)  I assume that you have 2,500 shares since you said 25 contracts and covered, yes?  There's no 'write' or wrong answer but why do the Nov 15th expiration for only 11 cents?  You could get 7x that for next week's $16.50 call.  Or do a $16/$16.5 Repair for next week for a credit of 66 cents and walk away with $17.66 if assigned at $16.50 instead of $16.61.  If you're going to play chicken with the oncoming train, at least play for something worthwhile.